# How to assign the cell in the formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have created VBA that opens another excel and takes value from another cells. I use index, indirect function:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
 "=IF(RC[-13]=0,"""",IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(""'[excel 2020 07 BB_v1.xlsm]""&MID(CELL(""filename"",R1C1),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R1C1))+1,255)&""'!$N$2:$N$512""),MATCH(RC[-13],INDIRECT(""'[excel 2020 07 BB_v1.xlsm]""&MID(CELL(""filename"",R1C1),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R1C1))+1,255)&""'!$A$2:$A$512""),0)),""N/A""))"
   Range("N2").Select
```

I want to assign the cell with the excel name that I will not need to change every time the title of the name (excel 2020 07) in the code. Could you please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate strings (and variables) with `&`:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]=0,"""",IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(""'[" & Range("N2").Value & " BB_v1.xlsm]""&MID
```

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).